# Swift Delegate from Singleton not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement SharedInstanceDelegate in App class. I have no idea why the functions under the protocol are not being called.

This is my Protocol and class.

```
class App {

    let sharedInstance = SharedInstance.shared

    init() {
        self.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    }
}

extension App: SharedInstanceDelegate {

    func1() { } // this is not executed
    func2() { }
}

protocol SharedInstanceDelegate: class {

   func1()
   func2()
}

class SharedInstance {

    static let shared = SharedInstance()
    weak var delegate: SharedInstanceDelegate?

    private init() { }

    func method1() {

        self.delegate?.func1() // this is executed
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the `class` keyword of the `SharedInstanceDelegate` with `protocol`. And remoce the `: class` part too. `SharedInstanceDelegate` should be a protocol that `App` should conform too.

Comment: @Prientus I updated the question. It was a typo, the actual code has the protocol keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you meant to make `SharedInstanceDelegate` a protocol, but you've made it a class. In either case, `App` does not conform/inherit `SharedInstanceDelegate`, so it's not clear how this would even compile.

Comment: Ugh! I fixed that. It was a protocol. I did not copy-paste the code to StackOverflow, I rewrote it. So, still not calling.

Comment: It's not clear here when `method1()` is called. Is it called before or after `App.init`? What is `delegate` at that point in time (check in the debugger). What is retaining `App`? (If nothing except this delegate variable, then it will immediately deallocate, since it's `weak`; what creates `App` and holds onto it?)  Do you know that `method1()` is being called on the `shared` instance and not some other instance? Basically, you'll figure this out by putting a debugger on it and seeing when each line of code is called, and exactly what each variable holds at the time it's called.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement your code to work with the delegate:

```
class App {

    let sharedInstance = SharedInstance.shared

    init() {
        self.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    }
}

extension App: SharedInstanceDelegate {

    func func1() { } // this will run now
    func func2() { }
}

protocol SharedInstanceDelegate {
    func func1()
    func func2()
}

class SharedInstance {

    static let shared = SharedInstance()
    var delegate: SharedInstanceDelegate?

    private init() { }

    func method1() {

        self.delegate?.func1() // this is executed
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It was a protocol, updated the question. But still not calling.

Comment: @RobertSandru I made some more changes as you might notice. Gave the functions you had the 'func' keyword and made the delegate non weak since its a protocol and not a class. I ran this code on a playground and it calls `func1` successfully. Are you using a playground or an actual project?

Answer (score 0):

Still no idea why this was happening, but cleaning the project fixed this. This is very strange. I have other delegates that call successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could work but it depends on how you are calling func1(). Calling it like this:

```
let testinstance = App().sharedInstance
testinstance.delegate?.func1()
```

will not work because you are not holding on to the App object. In this case the App object is the delegate, but because its a weak member and no one is retaining it, it gets released right away.

If you call it like this:

```
let testapp = App()
testapp.sharedInstance.delegate?.func1()
```

it works. In this case the App object is being retained and is still around when func1() is called.

Either way the way these classes are related is confusing to me. Why have a separate SharedInstance class at all?